# Different epoch times on 2 machines: Where to configure correctly?

Tags: time, perl, time-zone

I have 2 linux machines that need to run a Perl script and access a database. 
The date (as reported by the `date` and `date -u` commands) is correct (within a couple of minutes), but returning epoch from Perl has a 1 hour difference resulting in having on one machine UTC epoch-timestamp and on the other the wanted CET.

date on A:

```
Tue Dec 11 13:34:09 CET 2012
```

date on B:

```
Tue Dec 11 13:33:20 CET 2012
```

The script uses Time::HiRes and gathering the localtime->epoch to generate a date.
I build a minimalistic following script to output the behaviour:

```
#/usr/bin/perl
#
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use Time::Piece;
#
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime(localtime->epoch,"%s");
print "$date->datetime"."\n";
print $date->tzoffset."\n";
print $date->epoch."\n";
```

Output Machine A:

```
Tue Dec 11 12:35:43 2012->datetime 
0 
1355229343
```

Output Machine B:

```
Tue Dec 11 13:34:25 2012->datetime 
0 
1355232865
```

So as you see something must be wrong, probably with timezone or something similar. But I don't know where to look and what to configure as `date` itself outputs the correct time.

Comment: Why don't you just just adjust the time within BIOS? This isn't a "time zone" problem.  This is clear by the fact they are only different by 1 minute and 11 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, but I guess either you didn't read the question carefully or I didn't make it clear enough: Look at the epoch timestamps -> those are the ones that differ over an hour but no timezone offset is set on any machine.

Comment: I read the question and the times are 1 minute 11 seconds different and set to `CET`.  Based on the output of the perl script I assume there is a configuration difference.

Comment: The output of date may differ only with minutes and this is ok. But the output of the perl script differs more than 1 hour.
This may be a configuration difference - I just don't know where to look what is wrong :-(. 'locale' is the same on both machines for every type.

Comment: Does `date -u` return correct values on both machines (within a few minutes)?

Comment: yes date -u differs for < 2 minutes.

Comment: Then why don't you use a system call (using `date`) to get the date instead of the Perl module? You should also make sure that both machines have the same versions of Perl and `Time::Piece`.